# Custom Prolog arithmetic function

Tags: prolog, operators, user-defined-functions

I'm looking for something like built-in arithmetic operators that has a return value in Prolog (specifically in SWI-Prolog). E.g. if you run `A is (1+2) + (3+2).`, it returns `A = 8.`.

How can I define `func` operator to do something like `+` operator?
E.g. `A is (2 func 3) func (4 func (2+1)).`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to situate your function `func` inline just as the `+` operator (along with many others), you'll need to define a precedence order for `func` and it's arguments. You can achieve this in SWI-PROLOG with [`op/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=op/3).

For example, the directive (preceding code where `func/2` is used):

```
:- op(500,yfx,func).
```

To implement `func/2`, you can either write a meta-interpreter for your language (i.e., you write a PROLOG program which parses term expressions including `func` and interprets them as you wish), or if `func/2` is strictly arithmetic, you can use [arithmetic_function/1](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=arithmetic_function/1) also as a directive, as follows:

```
:- arithmetic_function(func/2).
```

Testing this with the following definition for `func/2`:

```
func(X, Y, Z) :- 
    Z is X + Y.
```

Gives, with your example:

```
?- A is (2 func 3) func (4 func (2+1)).
A = 12.
```

Comment: Now that in the SWI Prolog's manual it says that this directive is deprecated, how would be an updated solution? Tx

Comment: Unsure why it was deprecated, best to ask [Jan Wielemaker](https://github.com/JanWielemaker) if you really need to know. My understanding is that it still works, even though it has been deprecated... am I wrong?

Answer (score 2):

It is in the manual, `arithmetic_function/1` will raise your relation into something which `is` can understand, see

```
http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_forobject=section(2,'4.26',swi('/doc/Manual/extendarith.html'))
```