# Comparing two list?

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to compare two lists by length and set the output to true or false.

```
min(List1, List2, output) :-
     length(List1, N),
     length(List2, M),
       output is N<M.
```

But I keep getting errors, what's the syntax for the lists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of problems here; @Enigmativity is right in that you need to make `Output` variable, but `is/2` isn't defined over the operator `<` (it's used to evaluate arithmetic expressions such as `+`, or [those that are user defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4179894/prolog-function)).

Instead, consider the following:

```
min(List1, List2, Output) :-
    length(List1, N),
    length(List2, M),
    (N < M ->
        Output = 'true'
    ;   Output = 'false'
    ).
```

Here, `N < M` is a **logical test** which either succeeds or fails. **If** `N < M` is true, implication `->` directs the interpreter to bind the `Output` variable to the atom `'true'`, **else** to `'false'`, indicating the length relationship between the lists that you've asked for. You can bind anything here as you like, not just atoms.

Executing this gives:

```
?- min([1,2,3,4],[1,2],Output).
Output = false.
```

If you want `min/3` to simply return the smaller of the two input lists, you can try:

```
min(List1, List2, Output) :-
    length(List1, N),
    length(List2, M),
    (N < M ->
        Output = List1
    ;   Output = List2
    ).
```

Executing this on the same example gives:

```
?- min([1,2,3,4],[1,2],X).
X = [1, 2].
```

Answer (score 0):

This might run faster than solutions than compare the lengths if there is a small and a very large list (as it will stop as soon as the end of the smallest list is reached).

```
min_list([_|L1t], [_|L2t], Output) :- min(L1t, L2t, Output), !.
min_list(_, [], false).
min_list([], _, true).
```

About the list syntax all you need to know is that lists are expressed as `[Head|Tail]` where `Head` is the first element of the list and `Tail` a sublist containing the rest of elements.

The `!` is the *cut operator* to avoid backtracking for exploring other solutions (if you don't use it there, the system will wait for you to press the semicolon if you want another answer, and then it will say `false`).

Predicate variables that are not used are expressed as an underscore (otherwise you will get a warning about singleton variables).

Answer (score -1):

The simple change here is:

```
min(List1, List2, Output) :-
    length(List1, N),
    length(List2, M),
    Output is N<M.
```

`Output` is a variable, not a term, so it should start with an upper-case character.

Does that solve your problem?

Comment: No, it gives me an undefined procedure error when I do something like: